# locking issue problem

Tags: multithreading, locking

I have a treeSet in a class
It also offers a couple of ways to modify the TreeSet collection:

1. addtoset
2. removefrom set
3. setitems

In addtoSetmethod i need to check if the item is already present in set ,if yes do nothin if not add the new item to set.

```
 public static void addto set(final String items){
    if(!set.contains(items){
   //do something
  }
 }

  public static boolean contains( final String items) {

    //check wether the items exists or not
    return channels.contains(channel);
 }
```

How i can introduce readWrite locking around the set....?

Comment: 10 questions, no accepts - makes me not want to answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is Java code, and (set) is a static object... how about something like this:

```
public static void addto_set(final String items) {
   synchronized(set) {
      if (!set.contains(items)) {
         // do something
      }
   }
}
```

(and similar for the contains() method, and any other methods that access (set))